# Return the default value in the TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

There are several filters on my site (by date, duration, and so on). Accordingly, from a large amount of data, the user can find what he needs

There is also a "reset all filters" button that resets all filters and returns the full list of products.

However, with one of the filters, I ran into a problem: in this filter, I use a TextField from the mui. And the problem is that the values ​​themselves, by which the desired products are filtered, are discarded, and what the user entered in the field remains unchanged.

I will give an example: The user filters only by this field. Having received any result, he wants to return to the original list and presses the "reset all filters" button. All filters are reset and the original list is returned, but the data entered in the field remains, that is, the field itself is not cleared.

Help solve the problem

```
    const MAX_DURATION = 9999999 

export default function FilterDuration() {
  const [minDuration, setMinDuration] = useState(0);
  const [maxDuration, setMaxDuration] = useState(MAX_DURATION);

  useEffect(() => {
    updatedFilters.durationRange = { min: minDuration, max: maxDuration }
    setFilters(updatedFilters)
    if (maxDuration === 0) {
      setMaxDuration(MAX_DURATION)
    }
  }, [minDuration, maxDuration])

  return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>

        <div style={{ width: "120px" }}>
          <TextField
           
            onInput={(e) => {
              
              const newValue = Number(e.target.value)
              if (newValue )
                setMinDuration(newValue)


            }} />
        </div>

      </div>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `value` prop to your `TextField` which has the `minDuration` like this:

```
          <TextField
            type='number'
            size="small"
            margin="dense"
            label="From"
            value={minDuration}
            onInput={(e) => {
              e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value)).toString().slice(0,7)
              const newValue = Number(e.target.value)
              if (newValue <= maxDuration && newValue >= 0 && newValue <= MAX_DURATION)
                setMinDuration(newValue)


            }} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the value of the `TextField` to be managed by the state of your component. Add a `value` attribute and set it to the current value of `minDuration`:

```
<TextField
    ...
    value={minDuration}
/>
```